# Generating a top N selection at random

Tags: python, random

Given a list of photos:

```
set 1 : 14 photos
set 2 : 4 photos
set 3 : 2 photos

[{'set' : 1,'photos' : ['photo1','photo2'....'photo14']}, {'set' : 2,.....]
```

I want to display 10 images to the user. I want it so that set 1 is **most likely to dominate the list** (say, 6 out of 10 images) whereas the other sets are not **unfairly penalized** for having small numbers.

What is a simple robust algorithm which results in such esthetically pleasing random choices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import random
photos = [{'set' : 1,'photos' : ['photo1','photo2'....'photo14']}, {'set' : 2,.....]
weight = {1: 6, 2: 3, 3: 1} # set : number of shown photos
show = []
for d in photos:
    show.extend(random.sample(d['photos'], weight[d['set']]))
random.shuffle(show)
# show now contains a shuffled list of 6 photos from set 1, 3 from set 2 and 1 from set 3
```

Comment: This is perfect, as it works exactly as the weight tells it to